# How to retrieve zoom level in google maps?

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm trying to retrieve the mapView current zoom level in google maps using Swift. The documentation states that it should be `mapview.camera.zoom` but Xcode states that there is no such method.

```
let camera = self.mapView.camera.zoom
```

error I receive
 "Value of type '(GMSCoordinateBounds, UIEdgeInsets) -> GMSCameraPosition?' has no member 'zoom'"

[image]

Comment: please show more code as the docs are totally right. a GMSCameraPosition has a zoom :) -- po the map view ... does it even have a camera?

Comment: please take a look at the update code

Answer (score 0):

You can get Zoom level in this way...

```
let zoom = self.mapView.camera.zoom
```

Comment: which version of Google Maps are you using because this does not work. it gives this error "Value of type '(GMSCoordinateBounds, UIEdgeInsets) -> GMSCameraPosition?' has no member 'zoom'"

Comment: am using swift 2.3

Comment: Which version of gms are you using @pprevalon

Comment: im using the current version im not sure how to check the version. its very weird that this is not working. @Daij-Djan are you on the latest version if sure can you verify this is not working